# mouse cursor stops intermittently in plasma on ubuntu 22

Tags: 22.04, mouse, touchpad, asus, plasma

My system is an ASUS RoG Strix Scar II, and I'm running Linux 5.15.0-91 on Ubuntu 22 and a Plasma 4:5.24.7 desktop (not sure any more if it was a Kubuntu or Ubuntu ISO).

Recently I started noticing that the mouse pointer does not move from time to time when I used the touchpad. When the pointer moves it has the right speed, but every so many seconds it stops for about half a second.

It's similar to what happens on a VNC/RDP session with a slow network.

It's unclear to me what triggers it. Moving the mouse around for ages is fine, but changing windows or changing from keyboard to mouse/touchpad seems to make it happen more.

Because it started with the touchpad I thought its drivers were the issue, but reinstalling those did not help. And now that I use a mouse again (USB, optical, Kensington) it is also happening there.

Also I turned off Zoom in Desktop Effects, changed the refresh rate from 144Hz to 60 Hz as per previous suggestions, but the effect is still there.

So if it's not that, I presume this is the display configuration? The drivers, including the Nvidia ones (drivers version 535, cuda 11.5) are automatically updated by APT.

Previous posts mentions compositors etc but I don't use those (knowingly). Does anyone know what it could be? I have access to everything but not sure what to send.